# rJava fails on test of installation

Tags: rjava

Within R I believe I have Java configured correctly.

install.packages("rJava")

checks for a compiler and compiles several things

I do get the following

warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.4

Note: examples/rtest.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

and then I reach.....

** testing if installed package can be loaded

Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:

call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)

error: unable to load shared object '/u/US_HOME3/David/usr/lib64/R/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':

libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Error: loading failed

Execution halted

I'm left believing "Within R I believe I have Java configured correctly" must be false, but I'm not sure what to look at to remedy the situation.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's trying and failing to load .so libraries from that path /u/US_HOME3/insights/usr/lib64/R/library/rJava/libs.  Does it exist?  If not, maybe you need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH appropriately.

Comment: Well, no it doesn't exist. rJava is what I'm trying to install. to continue the string a bit from the log....                                                          Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing '/u/US_HOME3/insights/usr/lib64/R/library/rJava'

Comment: I don't think you have Java configured correctly.

Comment: And that was exactly so. One of the Java pointers was not correct. Got that pointed in the correct location and things went swimmingly.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Well done.